# When is the Blue Exorcist movie set?

Tags: blue-exorcist

When is the *Blue Exorcist* movie set, chronologically?

I'm sure there were cues in the movie to indicate where the movie falls relative to the TV series, but it's been ages since I watched the series, so I didn't really pick up on anything.

Comment: It's likely to be after the TV series, but since the anime branched off from the manga at around chapter 13, there's no frame of reference in respects to the anime, except for the festival that happens every 11 years.

Comment: WAIT, BLUE EXORCIST IS A MOVIE!!!

Comment: @Jonco98 Yes, a movie premiered in December 2012, and is now available on home video.

Comment: @senshin Great!

Comment: It's set after the series. If you notice he is not hiding his tail like he used to in the first half of the series. Thats how I worked it out. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short version

It probably takes place between episode 19 and 20.

#### Long version (spoilers)

> I was wondering about this as well. It clearly takes place after episode 15 when Rin reveals his powers, and after Konekomaru begins to accept him as a friend after episode 18 or 19. So I'd say it takes place before episode 20, because the next few episodes seem to happen concurrently and all are more serialized leading up to the finale. Also, Yukio doesn't have his pointy demon ears in the movie like he does in the after credits scenes of episode 25, so I don't think the movie takes place after the series.

Comment: But should I watch the movie before the second season or after the second season?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be after the series as Yukio isn't like he was at the end like how Rin is but Rin is known as the son of Satan now so I say anywhere from 19-20